# [firebase_messaging]: iOS FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage return null when click on Notification in killed State

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-file

Flutter iOS FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage return null when click on Notification in killed State.. I am not receiving data.

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Get the FCM token from the app
Send a notification using the FCM token using the c# payload
Receive Notification in iOS device when app is Killed.
Click on Notification -> App open and Load Home page with default data. But No data is shown which is send in Notification
Expected behavior

FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()should return value when click on notification.

Sample project

`

I had done all things and Every time getInitialMessage = null.